# Broadcasting udp datagram packet to connected clients not working

Tags: java, networking, udp, serversocket

I have multiple transmitters configured to send back a response when they receive a broadcast packet sent from a server through local port 5255, remote port 5252 containing the string "AST show me\0" (as stated in transmitters' manual). This should help me to scan for all the transmitters within the local network. I have implemented a server side code to broadcast that string message, but when I run the code , it have a bug at the following line code :

```
  socket.receive(packet1);
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong or missing in this code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: If it might help : The transmitters' IP address are 192.168.40.* ; and the server IP address is 192.168.40.254.

Thanks in advance !!

Here is the code :

```
package socket_test;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Server_UDP_Broadcast {

//@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    try{
        socket = new DatagramSocket(5255);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);

        //broadcast the string to the transmitters
        String str = "AST show me\0";
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        buf = str.getBytes();
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
        DatagramPacket packet;
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, 5252);
        socket.send(packet);
        System.out.println("Sent packet : " +packet.getData().toString());

        // receive response and display
        byte[] buf1 = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(buf1, buf1.length); 
        socket.receive(packet1);   
        String received = new String(packet1.getData(), 0, packet1.getLength());
        System.out.println("Answer from Transmitters :: " + received);          

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here are the bugs :

```
Sent packet : [B@70dea4e
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData (Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
at socket_test.Server_UDP_Broadcast.main(Server_UDP_Broadcast.java:32)
```

Comment: yes, I also understood from the error message that the server does not get  any response within the 10s timeout. Well, don't know if it is due to wrong programming or something else ?   For more details (if it would be helpful) the transmitters and the server are all connected via a switch in a local network. I have set the server IP to 192.168.40.254 and the transmitters' IP to 192.168.40.17 and 192.168.40.20 (the ping from the server to transmitters is working fine).  What might be the problem then ??

Answer (score 0):

> The transmitters' IP address are 192.168.40.*

So broadcast to `192.168.40.255`.

Comment: I have just tried broadcasting to 192.168.40.255, but still getting the same error message